# C# SQL statement Date Range

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, asp.net-web-api

I would like to use SQL statement to "filter" or display the data that lies within date range.

Here is an example:

```
SELECT PRODUCTNAME, PRODUCTID, DESCRIPTION, EXPIREDDATE 
FROM PRODUCT TABLE 
WHERE EXPIREDDATE < (SELECT GETDATE())
```

The above query is able to get `ExpiredDate` of an product for example.

Now I am trying to let user know the following month (which will be inputted by themselves) list of product that are going to expired.

Let me elaborate: if user enters '3', then starting from today let's say *2020-01-01*, until the next 3 months which will be *2020-04-01*, while the `ExpiredDate` falls within that daterange, the list of product will be shown back to the user

```
public object expiredProduct (int month) //month will be user inputted value 
{
    // I skipped database connection here
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();

    // what should I write here for comparing the date?
    command.CommandText = SELECT PRODUCTNAME, PRODUCTID, DESCRIPTION, EXPIREDDATE FROM PRODUCT TABLE WHERE EXPIREDDATE < (SELECT GETDATE())  

    return list; // I return back my data here
}
```

How should I write for the above query?

**Requirement**

My date is `DateTime` datatype. I am using C# Web API.

Comment: You'll want to add parameters to `command.Parameters` and reference them in the query.

Comment: @John do you mean that I need to create 2 parameters, which store today date `SELECT GETDATE()` and another date respectively?
But now I stuck at how to add the *month* based on user input to today date

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use parameters to define the upper and lower bound of your date range - something like this:

```
public object expiredProduct (int month) //month will be user inputted value 
{
    // I skipped database connection here
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();

    // what should I write here for comparing the date?
    command.CommandText = @"SELECT PRODUCTNAME, PRODUCTID, DESCRIPTION, EXPIREDDATE 
                            FROM PRODUCT TABLE 
                            WHERE EXPIREDDATE BETWEEN @FromDate AND @ToDate;";

    // then set these values
    command.Parameters.Add("@FromDate", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = DateTime.Today;
    command.Parameters.Add("@ToDate", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = DateTime.Today.AddMonths(month);

    return list; // I return back my data here
}
```

Comment: Thanks @marc_s! For additional information, may I know that if we could just add the `month` directly using C# code (not via Linq)?

Comment: @Lawraoke: that's not LINQ - that's standard C# / Base Class Library code